# Salesforce debug log filters stuck and will not change

Tags: debugging, salesforce

The debug log filters in my orgs are set as follows (copied straight from a debug log):

APEX_CODE,FINE;APEX_PROFILING,FINE;DB,INFO;VALIDATION,INFO;WORKFLOW,FINEST

No matter what I try, these settings will not change, and because several of them are set to fine/finest they make my debug logs hit maximum size:

***** MAXIMUM DEBUG LOG SIZE REACHED ***********

They max out so quickly that none of the debug statements that I place in my code are ever even reached, which makes the logs useless.

I have tried changing the filters in the Debug Log section of my org, I have tried the developer console, and using the Eclipse IDE. I have tried this in my Dev org and in Sandbox. Nothing helps. These settings will not change.

Anyone encounter this before, or know a way to override these options?

Comment: Are you setting the logginglevel in your code? This would override any changes you make to APEX_CODE at least. Look for the following:

System.LoggingLevel

Comment: @grigriforce Even if I change  the logging level, the debug log size maxes out before it hits my code (this is mostly due to the org's many workflow rules)

Comment: Can you check the relevant classes/triggers to see if you are overriding the default log filters for those classes? If you aren't and still can't get it working right then I would set them manually for each class. I.E. override the log filters for all classes you don't care about to 'none' and set the one you care about correctly.

Comment: Overriding log filters on a class to class basis has no effect.

Comment: Are you running testmethods by any chance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Debug log levels in Salesforce can be set in a number of different places that override each other so it's not always clear which log levels your code will execute with. I've listed them in order from least to most precedence below: I.E. 2 overrides 1, 3 overrides 1 and 2.

1. **debug log filters** - log levels set on the debug log page under setup.
2. **developer console** - log levels set in the developer console under workspace management
3. **apex class/trigger** - log levels set from the detail page of apex classes or triggers. You should see PUSH_TRACE_FLAGS and POP_TRACE_FLAGS in the debug log when you are overriding filters for the class/trigger.

**Caveat emptor:** Debug log filtering does not work correctly for [testmethods](http://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000iKMpAAM). All tests run with a predefined set of filters.

Comment: I never actually figured this out, even the senior SF devs I talked to didn't know what was going on... Hoping it's just a fluke, I think if it happens again I'll just submit a ticket with Salesforce. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yeah, these types of issues where it's probably a sf bug but there's nothing on the boards or ideaexchange are the worst.

Comment: This is really interfering with my custom legal app.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too recently. Whenever I changed the debug filter settings and clicked on save, debug log was not filtered according to filter settings, and when I checked the filter settings again, they were set as if I haven't changed them in the first place - as if no changes that I made on filter settings were saved.

Once I have deleted my user in the debug log 'Monitored Users' list and created it again, everything worked fine - I was able to edit the filter settings, save it (SF finally remembered the changes) and debug log was filtered according to the filters...

If this doesn't work, try deleting it again and setting it again, I think it started to work for me only after I deleted it the second time :)

**EDIT:** I remembered now that I saw in the developer console that there were no 'NONE' options offered when overriding the debug filters, so in my last attempt, I tried to set it in a way that no filter was set to 'NONE'. The idea behind that was that there is a possibility of a SF internal bug with handling filter values somewhere behind the curtains...

Good luck!